# How to get the active image object attributes(id, src) drawn on canvas html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am making a tool to draw images on canvas, according to which user can click on the images shown on left sidebar, then the images are drawn on the canvas, i am using [fabric js library](http://fabricjs.com/%E2%80%8E) to darg, drop, re-size, scale image. So that user can modify the image accordingly. You can see the scenario in the given picture.
[image]

From the area marked one i click on the image then the image is drawn on the area marked 2, and the stucture is soimething like that : 
A parent div (with tshirt image background)
then a canvas inside this div, (you can see it in black dashed border,)

Now the problem is to i want to get the **id** or **src** of the active image on the canvas, i can fire an event when any object is active on the canvas, so all i want to know is how to get the id of the object i selected, (means active object,) see the pic given below :

[image]

So now how can i get which image is active ? i mean what is the id or source of image i selected,  ? is this possible to get the id or image source after drawing them on canvas, if the user drawn 3 images on the canvas and he selected one , then how can i know which image is selected by user?

Comment: you code should be added here, we are not ought to look for it somewhere out SO.

Comment: @Omar Actually, i should have pasted the code here, but code is too much lengthy, so any help from your side would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

Comment: Its more appropriate to mention that and add a pastebin/fiddle, rather than asking others to your webpage to look for it.

Comment: @PranshuJain - here's an example: `var activeObject; canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) {
  activeObject = e.target;
});`.

Comment: @joe Thanks for a positive response, kindly let me try.

Comment: `var id = $('img:selected').attr('id');`

Comment: @Joe Couldn't succeed mate.

Comment: @Omar when i alerted it is giving : undefined in alert box.

Comment: As per you webpage, images has no id.

Comment: @Omar They have a id, i think you are looking at the tshirt images, right bro ? go for small graphics images, go to Choose design tab, they you will find, or you can go to line number : 788, and there you will find the images, they have id like scream, scream1.

Comment: @Joe : Which event is there to show alert when we drag and change dimensions of active element on canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this problem, we can achieve this via **get("src")** like, **activeobject.get("src")**